# Toshiba satellite c640 laptop screen going dark when charger unplugged

Tags: laptop, display, battery, toshiba-laptop

My Toshiba satellite c640 laptop screen going dark, when I unplug the charger.

On plugging charger screen is blinking for 5-10 minutes, then stops blinking.

Anybody know whats happening with my laptop?

Please don't consider this as a duplicate question. I have tried almost everything from other answers like adjusting power plans, replacing battery etc.

1. How dark (off vs. dimmed)?

   The screen is dimmed (too dark). But when I used my torch I can see screen contents. Please see image below

   [image]
2. What blinks when plugging it in again (entire display cycles on and off, or an indicator LED flashes)?

   Entire display cycles on and off
3. Does this happen on a fully-charged good battery?

   Always
4. How long ago did it start?

   One week
5. Were there any changes or updates before the problem started? How old is the laptop?

   No, I am just using my laptop to check emails. Nothing else. Laptop is 2 years old

Comment: How dark (off vs. dimmed)?  What blinks when plugging it in again (entire display cycles on and off, or an indicator LED flashes)?  Does this happen on a fully-charged good battery?  How long ago did it start?  Were there any changes or updates before the problem started?  How old is the laptop?  Just saying it isn't a duplicate of any other question isn't helpful.  List specifically everything you've tried so people don't suggest the same solutions.

Comment: OK, thanks for considering my question, I will update with relevant things you asked.

Comment: Just a wild guess that it has fluorescent backlighting that's failing.  It's only trying to come on when it's plugged in, and the blinking is the tubes cycling on but not staying lit.

Comment: Here is a link:    http://www.laptoppanel.com.au/Toshiba_Satellite_C640_LED_screen_LCD    ,     which a little description of some components around the display. Perhaps helpful.

Comment: From GiaRui's link, it looks like at least the replacement screen is LED backlit.  A quick search didn't indicate whether the original was, also.

Comment: Will it helps,if I replace screen??and how much it will costs??

Comment: We're only guessing at the cause, so obviously, you would want to get it diagnosed, but replacing the screen assembly (basically everything inside the lid), would fix any problem originating in the screen.  Unfortunately, the cost is a substantial portion of a new laptop.  Typically, laptops are much older than 2 yrs when the screen fails, so lots of other parts are approaching end of life, and it isn't worth the repair.  On a 2 yr old laptop, that's something you'll need to weigh when you get an estimate.  Depending on what's actually wrong, it might not require a new screen.

Comment: Have you investigated the power settings in your OS?